# How can I DRY this <div> with Rails Forms?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I understand that with Rails Form Helpers, I can pass in classes, placeholders, types, etc. into Rails, so instead of writing

```
<input id="name" name="name" type: "text" pattern="" value="Kanye West"/>
<label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="name">Enter Name</label>
```

I can do:

```
<%= f.text_field :name, class: 'mdl-textfield__input', type: 'text', pattern: '-?[0-9]*(\.[0-9]+)?', id: 'name', value: 'Kanye West' %>
<label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="name">Enter Name</label>
```

But it becomes pointless, because if I use a CSS framework, it ends up looking like this...

```
<div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--6-col mdl-cell--4-col-tablet hide-dis">
  <div class="mdl-textfield advanced-input mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--expandable">
    <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label">
      <%= f.text_field :name, class: 'mdl-textfield__input', type: 'text', pattern: '-?[0-9]*(\.[0-9]+)?', id: 'name', value: 'Kanye West' %>
      <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="name">Enter Name</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can imagine how ugly this can get when you have 10 form elements, right. I could try *partializing* it, but I don't know how I would pass in the `f.textfield` part. Please let me know how I can improve this mess and **or anything else that you see that can be improved with me code :)**

Comment: Have a look at simple_form gem. It let's you painlessly write helper functions for custom inputs. It also supports bootstrap if you're interested in that.

Comment: My only concern is we are also using a Cocoon GEM which, as it describes, allows you to nest forms. You can imagine, it gets very messy editing, populating and deleting subsects of forms.

Answer (score 2):

You can create your own [FormBuilder](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder.html) and create custom controls that include the wrapper classes than you need.

For example if you want to wrap your text fields in a particular `div`:

```
class CustomFormBuilder < ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder
  def custom_text_field(method, tag_value, options = {})
    @template.content_tag(:div,
      @template.text_field(
        @object_name, method, tag_value, objectify_options(options)
      ),
      class: 'mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield'
    )
  end
end
```